# Material UI TextField does not work with useForm when refactored out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-form

So I have a form, and here is one of the inputs:

[image]

The issue is the error never goes away even when I try to submit the form.
So whats really weird is that it was working before with this old code (error goes away when user types into input and hits submit):

```
                `<FormControl sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
                  <MuiTextField
                    {...register("usernameNormal", {
                      required:
                        form.connections?.sftp?.loginType === "Normal" ||
                        !form.connections?.sftp?.loginType,
                    })}
                    id="username"
                    label="Username"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={handleNormalUsernameChange}
                    value={form.connections?.sftp?.usernameNormal}
                    error={errors.usernameNormal}
                  ></MuiTextField>
                </FormControl>
                {errors.usernameNormal && (
                  <FormHelperText
                    style={{ marginTop: "-32px", color: "red" }}
                    id="component-error-text"
                  >
                    Username is a required field
                  </FormHelperText>
                )}`
```

But I'm trying to refactor our TextField into a shared component but for some reason no matter what I do the error *always* persists.

I got to the point where I literally just rendered the MuiTextField in a dummy component:

`const TestTextField = (props) => { return <MuiTextField {...props} />; };`

And then just rendered it the same, using my dummy component:

```
<FormControl sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
                      <TestTextField
                        {...register("usernameNormal", {
                          required:
                            form.connections?.sftp?.loginType === "Normal" ||
                            !form.connections?.sftp?.loginType,
                        })}
                        id="username"
                        label="Username"
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={handleNormalUsernameChange}
                        value={form.connections?.sftp?.usernameNormal}
                        error={errors.usernameNormal}
                      ></TestTextField>
                    </FormControl>
                    {errors.usernameNormal && (
                      <FormHelperText
                        style={{ marginTop: "-32px", color: "red" }}
                        id="component-error-text"
                      >
                        Username is a required field
                      </FormHelperText>
                    )}
```

And it still doesn't work...

Essentially, it works when I directly use the `MuiTextField` but when I replace it with my dummy `TestTextField` which literally just renders `MuiTextField` it doesn't work (error always persists)

We are using the [useForm](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform) library to manage the errors and it looks like the `error` object is just never updated unless you *directly* use the MaterialUI TextField. This makes no sense to me.

Does anything stick out as obviously wrong here?